# Java Singly Linked Integer List, write function thats returns a reference to element with index I in the list

Tags: java, get, linked-list

I have been trying to write a Java function `IntList get(int i)` that is supposed to return a reference to the `i-th` element in a singly linked integer list. 
My problem is that the function returns `null`, even if I try to reference an existing element!

```
public class IntList {

    private int info;                   //the int data of this list element  
    private IntList next;                   //the rest of the list

    /**
    * Sets up a new instance of IntList corresponding to the given info and next.
    * @param info the int data of this list element
    * @param next the rest of the list
    */
    public IntList(int info, IntList next) {
        this.info = info;
        this.next = next;

    }

    /**
    * A new list where the given info has been prepended.
    * @param info the int data of the new list element
    * @return a new instance of IntList
    */
    /*
    public IntList prepend(int info) {
        return new IntList(info, this);

    }
    */

    /** 
    * A new list where the given info has been appended.
    * @param info the int data of the new list element
    * @return a new instance of IntList
    */
    public IntList append(int info) {
        if(next == null) {
            return new IntList(this.info, new IntList(info, null));

        } else {
            return new IntList(this.info, next.append(info));

        }
    }

    /**
    * Commputes the sum of all elements of this list.
    * @return the sum of all elements
    */
    public int sum() {
        if(next == null) {
            return info;

        } else {
            return info + next.sum();

        }
    }

    /**
    * Auxiliary function for the reversal of this list.
    * @param acc the list elements accumulated so far
    * @return a new instance of IntList
    */
    private IntList reverseAux(IntList acc) {
        if(next == null) {
            return new IntList(info, acc);

        } else {
            return next.reverseAux(new IntList(info, acc));

        }
    }

    /**
    * A new list with the elements of this list in reverse order. 
    * @return   a new instance of the IntList
    */
    public IntList reverse() {
        return reverseAux(null);

    }

    /**
    * String representation of this list.
    */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(next == null) {
            return "" + info;

        } else {
            return info + " , " + next;

        }
    }

    /**
    * An integer array is converted to a list
    * @param values is an array containing integer elements
    * @return a new instance of IntList
    */
    public static IntList fromArray(int[] values) {
        int n = values.length;
        IntList res = new IntList(values[0] , null);

        for(int i = 1; i < n ; i ++) {
            res = res.append(values[i]);

        }
        return res;

    }

    /**
    * The length of a given IntList object is determined
    * @return the length of the list
    */
    public  int length() {
        int counter = 1;

        while(next != null) {
            counter = counter + 1;

            next = next.next;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public IntList get(int i) {


        for(int k = 0 ; k < i - 1 ; k ++) {

            if(next != null) {
                next = next.next;
            }

        }
        return next;

    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntList lst = new IntList(1, null);

        for(int i = 2 ; i < 10 ; i ++) {
            lst = lst.append(i);    
        }

        System.out.println(lst);
        System.out.println(lst.reverse());
        System.out.println(lst.sum());

        int[] values = new int[4];
        values[0] = 3;
        values[1] = 4;
        values[2] = 5;
        values[3] = 8;

        System.out.println(fromArray(values));
        System.out.println(lst.length());
        System.out.println(fromArray(values).length());
        System.out.println(lst.get(2));

    }   




}
```

Since my implementation of the list does not require two separate classes for nodes and the list itself, I cannot find any valuable information on the web (most people use two classes).

Comment: Do you expect `lst.get(2)` to return `2`, `3`, `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`, or `3,4,5,6,7,8,9`?

Comment: Your get method is modifying the list. I assume this is unintended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works without checking for IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
public IntList get(int i) {
    IntList current = this;

    for(int k = 0 ; k < i - 1 ; k ++) {

        if(current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }

    }
    return current;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `length` method modifies next.  Make it recursive (or make a new variable to step through your list):

```
public int length() {
    if(next != null) {
        return 1 + next.length();
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Your `get` method also modifies the original list.  Recursive solution is:

```
public IntList get(int i) {
    if (i < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index is negative!");
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        return this;
    } else if (next != null) {
        return next.get(i - 1);
    }
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index exceeds bounds");
}
```

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException is more pertinent than IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: thank you for the tip, @Dunes.  I changed the exception being thrown

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this...

```
public IntList append(int info) {
    if(next == null) {
        return new IntList(info, this);

    } else {
        return new IntList(info, next);

    }
}
```

Comment: No this is not what I want at all Rocky :) . I am looking for a function get(int i) that returns a reference to the i.th element of my existing list. I do not want to append a random element to my list!

Comment: @Felix I think that @Rocky is suggesting that there may be something wrong with your append method, but after going over your method several times, yours seems doing its purpose.

Comment: My program works fine, other than the get() method. Can someone please help me implement the get() method? Thank you!